# VSCode : disable formatting of a specific file (or extension)

Tags: handlebars.js, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code, is it possible to disable the formatting of a specific file (or extension)?

I try to use some Handlebars templates and I don't want VSCode to format them, at all. A simple example would be :

```
{{test1}}

{{test2}}
```

When I save this file (I do have - and want - `"editor.formatOnSave"` set to `true`), VsCode transforms the content to

```
 {{test1}} {{test2}}
```

The only way I found for the file to stay untouched, is to name it "`template.txt`" instead of "`template.hbs`".

Any idea?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it asks about a single file and not a "language". I couldn't find an answer to this question, but a work around is to use `workbench.action.files.saveWithoutFormatting` when saving a file that one doesn't want to format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add file-specific exclusions like so:

```
"[handlebars]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false },
```

Comment: This doesn't seemt to work with glob such as `[*.test.fish]`

Comment: I would guess that's because `[handlebars]` isn't a file path like your glob is; it's a special VS code name for the language, and hence why that string is in the braces and instead of ".hbs"