# VS Code, how to exclude directory from editor.formatOnSave

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am using a php formatter in VSCode, my problem is that on some view files where there is also html the code get messy, so i am trying to exclude the folder from the formatOnSave

This is my current configuration.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[php]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

How can i have the php format on save on all folders except the view one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude files from "format on save" in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-files-from-format-on-save-in-vscode)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Prettier](https://prettier.io), then you can create a [.prettierignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files) file and include the directory that you want to exclude from formatting. You may need to go to the extension settings for Prettier and set the file path for .prettierignore for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify), then can use the `beautify.ignore` option:

> Example:
>
> ```
> /* ignore all files named 'test.js' not in the root folder,
>    all files directly in any 'spec' directory, and
>    all files in any 'test' directory at any depth
> */
> "beautify.ignore": ["*/test.js", "**/spec/*", "**/test/**/*"]
>
> /* ignore all files ending in '_test.js' anywhere */
> "beautify.ignore": "**/*_test.js"
> ```