# VSCode: turn off format on save only in specific directory

Tags: html, configuration, visual-studio-code, formatting

I'd like to configure VSCode to not auto-format files in a specific directory.

Background: I'm writing a library that renders json into html. For testing, I'm comparing the results with pre-rendered html snippets. Unfortunately, VSCode *cks up my formatting of the html files with it's auto-format feature. Although auto-formatting is very handy for my actual code, I'd like to turn it off for those snippets.

Is there any option to turn it off for files in a specific directory or for files matching a specific pattern in filename? If yes: Is it possible to have the settings stored in the project folder?

So far I only found [the option to turn auto-formatting on/off per language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-a-file-extension-from-format-on-save-in-vscode/44831631#44831631). This is close but not perfect, since there are other html files in my project that would benefit from auto-formatting.

Comment: I think you can only en/disable for an entire workspace. Perhps this hack would work for your case? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35350#issuecomment-393625854

Comment: Added that workaround to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-a-file-extension-from-format-on-save-in-vscode/44831631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add (for example, if you language is JavaScript):

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"files.associations": {
    "src/some-folder/*.js": "plaintext"
}
```

Comment: this will hurt the DX of these files, i.e. intellisense, extensions, etc

Comment: As those files are not supposed to be "developed in", DX is not my concern here. I create them by storing the output of my render function, checking manually if it looks like expected and then adding it to the tests to make sure that it stays that way even if I change the render function. So this answer is very useful because I actually treat those files like plain text.