# Can I prevent VSCode formatting a specific file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to prevent VSCode from automatically formatting a specific file, without disabling the formatting globally, or breaking the file's syntax highlighting (setting the `"files.associations"` setting)?

Please note: I am aware this is close to being a duplicate, but the other similar [questions and their related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-files-from-format-on-save-in-vscode) appear to be about ignoring file **types** rather than specific files.