# Why does on saving the .' .js' file chage the indentation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Whenever i enter click save my '.js ' file undergoes an indentation change . I have disabled beautify and prettier . Any other suggestion ?
[image: Here's the error that occured]

Comment: Disable format on save ?

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: CTRL SHIFT P -> `>Preferences: Open User Settings` -> `Editor: Format on Save`

Comment: not working brother ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude files from "format on save" in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831313/how-to-exclude-files-from-format-on-save-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definetly because of some Formatter being applied on `codeActionsOnSave`.

I see you got a notification in the bottom right from VS Code, often this informs you when linters collide.

Also check your `settings.json` of VS Code, found under Preferences > Settings > top right corner icon. It might be that there are some linters specified for specific files and also the `codeActionsOnSave`.

Alternatively you can create a .vscode folder in your root folder containing a `settings.json` that sets workspace specific rules that overwrite your VS Code settings for that workspace. E.g.

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed any "Linters" on VS code.
Here is the link if you want to know what are these:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_linters

or Probably it is the formatting issue:

The javascript.format.* settings configure the built-in formatter. Or, if the built-in formatter is getting in the way, set "javascript.format.enable" to false to disable it.
Link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_formatting