# How to exclude one specific file from "format on save" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is [a question about suppressing `editor.formatOnSave` *for specific file extensions (languages)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44831313/419956) but I have a *different* question instead: how can I suppress this feature for *one specific file* in my workspace?

I want to suppress it *in* the repository somehow, with a config or hint in a comment, or some such, so I can prevent anyone from accidentally doing it wrong. I cannot tell my 20ish teammates to always "save without formatting", nor could I myself remember that at all times.

I have a `./vscode/settings.json` file that has:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

and it works wonderfully for all files in my workspace. However, I want to suppress it for my `app-routing.module.ts` file (it's an Angular project) because the auto-formatting there hurts readability more than it helps.

**How to disable `editor.formatOnSave` for one specific file?**

When I or a colleague use "Save" (`CTRL + S` on Windows) or "Save All" (`CTRL + K, S` on Windows) the auto formatting should *not* be triggered for that file.

---

What I've tried:

- Check all answers [in the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44831313/419956) (so e.g. `"[javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false }`
- Have a `.vscode/settings.json` folder in subfolders, but [that's not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32693)
- Include `/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */` in my file (AFAIK prettier is my formatter for TypeScript files), and read through [this open prettier issue on GitHub](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3634)
- Create a `.prettierignore` file and add my file

None of these worked.

---

### Workaround

Almost two years later, and I noticed that if you place `// prettier-ignore` inside a file it *will* recursively ignore the next line *and all statements that are 'children' of that line*. So if you place it just above -say- your `@NgModule({` opening line, the entire class will be ignored.

For example:

```typescript
// prettier-ignore
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  nonprettymethod1() { console.log('Test'); }
  nonprettymethod2() {
    console.log('A very long line that would cause prettier to wrap it along mulitple lines as best it can.');
  }
}
```

Combined with these `.vscode/settings.json` settings:

```typescript
{
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Added my workaround to the end of the question; not posting it as an answer because it technically isn't one for me.

Comment: Why don't you consider the workaround an Answer? It seems like a good option (for anyone using Prettier).

Comment: The question is / was about suppressing prettier for _an entire file_, not just one class or function in a file. If I have for example one file with multiple small DTO's, or a component template with no top-level entry to slap the `// prettier-ignore` on, the workaround will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Just save your file with:

- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> on Linux and Windows
- <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> on Mac

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! My (default) mapping for that however is `saveAll`, doesn't that trigger said formatting? There is `CTRL + K` `CTRL + SHIFT + S` for `saveWithoutFormatting`, but that doesn't help my colleagues (or my own incidental mistake). I guess I'd prefer a way to enforce this _in_ the repository.

Comment: @Jeroen I don't know but actually I'd also be interested in such feature.