# How to exclude from formatting a family of files defined by a file extension in VSCode but still have syntax highlighting for those files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, ros2

The problem is as follow:

I have a file that quite follows the XML standard but add macros inside tags, however the parser for those macros is sensible to newlines.

I would like to see the syntax of the file highlighted as XML, but I would like the formatter not to format the file.

- If I associate the file with XML ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831631%5D)), I have the formatter and the syntax highlighting but I have those new lines that kill the parser.
- If I break the association of the file with XML, I lose the syntax highlighting.

I would basically need to have file association for syntax highlighting but not formatting.

The problem comes with the use of xacro files in ROS2.

Comment: set language specific settings, for the `xml` languageID disable the formatting

Comment: do you mean for format on save? or even when manually invoking formatting? if you're only interested in format on save, that's expressly out of scope for VS Code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147677 & https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176946